# MarkLogic - node.js Client API - queryBuilder query array of IDs

Tags: node.js, marklogic

This question is similar to:
[MarkLogic - XQuery - cts:element-range-query using variable length sequence or map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328309/marklogic-xquery-ctselement-range-query-using-variable-length-sequence-or-m/30353386#30353386)

But this time I need to do the query using the queryBuilder in the node.js client API.

I have a collection of 100,000 records structured like this:

```
<record>
    <pk>1</pk>
    <id>1234</id>
</record>
<record>
    <pk>2</pk>
    <id>1234</id>
</record>
<record>
    <pk>3</pk>
    <id>5678</id>
</record>
<record>
<pk>4</pk>
    <id>5678</id>
</record>
```

I have setup a range index on id.

I want to write a query using the queryBuilder node.js client API that will allow me to pass in an array of IDs and get out a list of records.

It needs to:
1) query a specific collection
2) leverage the range indexes for performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured out the problem.

```
db.db.documents.query(
  q.where(
    q.collection('Records'),
    q.or(
        q.value('id', ['1', '2'])
    )
  ).slice(1, 99999999)
)
```

I originally tried to pass an array into q.value and I was only getting limited results (Got 10 when I expected 20). So I was under the impression that I was doing it wrong.

It turns out I just needed to slice the where clause to include everything.  Apparently if you don't specify how much to take it defaults to 10.

Also note that when I tried .slice(0) which would have been preferred, I got an exception.

Comment: Because the database can contain many more documents than would be practical to retrieve in a single request, you should specify the largest number of documents you're willing to retrieve -- so your solution is correct; btw, .slice(0) returns no documents, which you would typically do only if getting facets.